# Бот дискорд, сравнение словарей

Tags: python, discord.py

Суть бота: человек пишет команду `!релиз *название_что_озвучить* *количество_людей_которые_озвучат*`, она создаёт два словаря, в одном ключ это название, что надо озвучить, а значение это количество людей, в другом ключ это тоже название, что озвучить, но значение 0, потому что изначально никто не озвучил.

Потом другие люди, которые должны это озвучить, пишут `!озвучил *название_что_озвучить*`, после чего добавляется к второму словарю по единичке, и должно сделаться так, чтобы словари сравнивались, и когда совпадали ключ: значение в обоих, ключ сохранялся в переменную, чтобы можно было сделать красивый вывод типа *название_релиза озвучено. Всем спасибо*.

Сделал цикл for для переборки словарей, но оно их не сравнивает... Пробовал много способов, пока что из возможных проблем вижу только то, что в первый словарь данные записываются *название: (*цифра*,)*, а во второй *название: (цифра)* (без запятой). Думаю, по этому оно и не сравнивает ключи/значения вместе, как нужно. Если сравнивать отдельно ключи, цикл работает, а вот отдельно значения - нет.

Прошу вашей помощи, так как уже перепробовал все известные мне методы. Код ниже, закомментировал возможно непонятные части.

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
from config import settings
intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.message_content = True
reliz_value = '' # объявляем, кто это такой
itog = 'None'
title = {

} # здесь хранятся релизы
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='!', intents=intents)
max_count = {

} # максимум дабберов
max_counts = 0 # начальное значение максимума дабберов

@bot.command(name='озвучил') # не передаём аргумент pass_context, так как он был нужен в старых версиях.
async def озвучил(ctx, *, taytle): # создаём функцию и передаём аргумент ctx
    author = ctx.message.author # объявляем переменную author и записываем туда информацию об авторе.
    # функция ctx - команда связанная с текстом
    await ctx.send(f'{author.mention} сдал озвучку! Похлопаем в ладоши :)') # Выводим сообщение с упоминанием автора, обращаясь к переменной author
    max_count[taytle] += 1
    global itog
    # цикл, перебирающий ключи и значения, а потом выводящий чисто ключи
    for name in title.items():
        for name2 in max_count.items():
            if name == name2:
                itog = name
                
    
@bot.command(name='релиз')
async def релиз(ctx, reliz: str, *max_dubbers: int): # ctx - текстовый параметр
    # сохраняется в перменную reliz, * показывает, что параметр обязателен
    author = ctx.message.author # объявляем переменную author и записываем туда информацию об авторе.
    await ctx.send(f'Был выбран релиз: "{reliz}". Начинаем работать :)') # показывает, какой релиз был выбран
    max_count[reliz] = 0 # сколько минимум дабберов в каком тайтле
    title[reliz] = max_dubbers # добавляется в словарь тайтлов / кол-во дабберов 
    await ctx.send(f'{title}')
    await ctx.send(f'{max_count}')

@bot.command(name='инфо')
async def инфо(ctx): # ctx - текстовый параметр
    reliz_value = list(title)
    await ctx.send(f'Активные релизы: {reliz_value}') # показывает список активных релизов

bot.run(settings['token']) # Обращаемся к словарю settings с ключом token, для получения токена
```

Answer (score 0):

Не знаю, зачем вы используете 2 словаря для этого, а потом их пытаетесь сравнить.

могу предложить сделать такую структуру словаря
Dict[str: (int, int)]

При получении команды `!релиз *название_что_озвучить* *количество_людей_которые_озвучат*` создавать запись:

```
dict[*название_что_озвучить*] = (0, *количество_людей_которые_озвучат*)
```

а при `!озвучил *название_что_озвучить*`
изменять словарь

```
val = dict.get(*название_что_озвучить*)
dict.update(*название_что_озвучить*, (val[0]+1, val[1]))
```

можно еще после обновления сделать проверку на всех сдавших, чтобы потом красиво вывести, например так:

```
if val[0]+1 == val[1]:
    *запустить функцию вывода*
```